# Messed my apt repo list, probably linked to language packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management, pop-os

I am having trouble updating pop os because my apt repo list appear not to be working correctly. Probably linked to language package issues, but I don't know how to get rid of this errors.

When I do

```
#sudo apt-get update                                                                                                                                                          tcapelle a[55/444]
Hit:1 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease
Hit:2 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 [http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary](http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary) focal InRelease
Hit:4 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal-backports InRelease
Ign:6 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal/main all Packages
Ign:6 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal/main all Packages
Err:6 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal/main all Packages
404  Not Found \[IP: [91.189.91.38](https://91.189.91.38) 80\]
Hit:7 [http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu](http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu) focal InRelease
Get:8 [https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu) focal InRelease \[36.2 kB\]
Hit:9 [https://repo.skype.com/deb](https://repo.skype.com/deb) stable InRelease
Hit:10 [http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode](http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode) stable InRelease
Hit:11 [https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams) stable InRelease
Hit:12 [https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian](https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian) jessie InRelease
Fetched 36.2 kB in 22s (1,661 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/source/Sources' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/source/Sources' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/source/Sources' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-all/Packages' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/i18n/Translation-en\_US' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/cnf/Commands-all' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository '[http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu) focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'restricted' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

If I look inside my sources.list file it looks normal:

```
# deb cdrom:[Pop_OS 20.04 _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200617)]/ focal main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal main
# deb-src http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal main

deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
```

other files in : `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov  6 19:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Nov 12 06:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   69 Aug 10 11:44 bluetooth-ubuntu-bluez-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Oct 23 10:26 skype-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Sep 17 14:42 slack.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Sep 17 14:42 slack.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Aug 10 11:44 spotify.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  124 Sep 17 14:42 system76-ubuntu-pop-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  124 Sep 17 14:42 system76-ubuntu-pop-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  196 Oct 16 14:00 teams.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Sep 17 14:42 vscode.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  193 Sep 17 14:42 vscode.list.save
```

Any idea?

Comment: Which languages are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed my issue:
First off, clean the APT list which may be corrupted:

```bsh
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Then, clean the Debian packaging modules:

```bsh
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
```

And replace the bad packaging module with the previous, working one:

```bsh
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Update the repository:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a few debug notes:

1. The IP reported in the error is correctly pointed to from the URI

```
$ nslookup us.archive.ubuntu.com
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   us.archive.ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.38
```

When I checked if there was a problem with the InRelase file, I inspected it per your first warning:

```
$ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease 
$ grep restricted/source/Sources InRelease
 074fdbcb6436a55b3289dd0b1700f747            37681 restricted/source/Sources
```

This InRelease file certainly has a restricted component.  Even if it didn't I took a look at the Sources.gz that this should point to and it certainly exists.

```
$ wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/restricted/source/Sources.gz
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Sources.gz                             100%[============================================================================>]   7.03K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s
```

Which translation are you looking for?  If look for `en_CA` I do find that it's only in `main` and `universe` while `ru` is in `main`, `multiverse`, `restricted`, `universe`

```
$ grep Translation-en_CA InRelease
 8e43eb4048d41d24b070726f61de4a0d            11684 main/i18n/Translation-en_CA
 694465955cefc44304388cc9e66a9ae8             1858 universe/i18n/Translation-en_CA

$ grep Translation-ru InRelease
 07e6358033ea05ed3dd0217fad125bec          2574447 main/i18n/Translation-ru
 a511b443d0a0ad65aef4fac59f2d7d2a           316225 multiverse/i18n/Translation-ru
 6586f7f8446a61e48ff1a4e65b800a2d             8515 restricted/i18n/Translation-ru
 f7b3223a7dae2f917dda9d19473ce67b          8102575 universe/i18n/Translation-ru
```

Comment: I installed Spanish and French languages